# How can an R package produce a p-value with an exponent of -237?

Tags: r

I'm using the R package MAST and it produces some impressively small P-values -- so small I didn't think they could be stored as regular floating point values. Quadruple precision reaches only $10^{-34}$ ([source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_epsilon)). How is this possible?

Comment: You misunderstand precision.  IEEE *double* precision represents numbers as small as 10^(-308): see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't just R; computers in general can store tiny numbers because floating point numbers are represented with a sign bit, a fraction, and an *exponent*. The space reserved for the exponent permits very large and very small numbers. See the [R documentation on machine precision](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.4.3/topics/.Machine) (noting e.g. the difference between `double.eps` and `double.xmin`), and the Wikipedia page on [IEEE 754-1985](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-1985) which describes the original standard for representing floating-point numbers (updated in 2008).